# What does `OWNER` value mean in Rules export?

Tags: rules

When exporting a rule from Rules module you get some serialized representation of that rule.
I understand everything but the 'OWNER' property in the export string - it has 'rules' value, but what does it mean specifically?

If I want store this rule in code within my module, do I need to change this value to 'module_name'? What are the implications here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OWNER means what module provided this rule. The reason for this is so we have a good way for contrib modules like drupal_commerce to have a section in their administrative area to only show an interface for their rules and not ALL rules.

Comment: So is it akin to TAGS? No functional purpose except for categorization?

Comment: From all of my past experience that is what I gathered.

Comment: I'd like to add one less-than-obvious consequence of this behavior that gave me troubles.
If you change 'OWNER' to something other than 'rules' you lose the ability to see/manipulate it through the standard Rules UI interface. So, beware.

Comment: Yes you will lose it via the UI. I'm sorry I thought I had mentioned that above. Rules' UI needs to be updated so that it is the catch all for any Rule regardless of OWNER.